# PHP convert divs to custom tags

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to convert some html tags to custom tags using PHP.  I've been trying to use DOMDocument but finding it to be incredibly cumbersome.  Is there a simple way to do this in PHP / DOMDocument?

**Input:**

```
<div class="element_wrapper">
    <div class="element_header">My header</div>
    <div class="element">
        <div class="name">Element Name</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<element_wrapper>
    <element_header>My Header</element_header>
    <element>
        <name>Element Name</name>
    </element>
</element_wrapper>
```

**My first approach (incomplete, added per AndrewL64's request):**

```php
<?php

$templates = Repository::fetchTemplates();

$classes = [
    'element_wrapper',
    'element',
    'name',
    'element_header',
];

foreach ($templates as $template) {
    $html = '<div>' . $template['html_body'] . '</div>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        $div_nodes = $finder->query("//div[@class='$class']");
        /** @var DOMNode $div_node */
        foreach ($div_nodes as $div_node) {

            /** @var DOMElement $custom_tag */
            $custom_tag = $dom->createElement($class, $div_node->nodeValue);
            if ($div_node->hasAttributes()) {
                foreach ($div_node->attributes as $attribute) {
                    if ($attribute->nodeValue === $class) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $custom_tag->setAttributeNode($attribute);
                }
            }
            $div_node->parentNode->replaceChild($custom_tag, $div_node);
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I did comment on what the downvote is for. You edited your question and then replied as though you had initially posted everything as you should. I will remove the downvote because you have posted your attempt to solve the problem as requested. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used `preg_replace` and multiple `DOMDocument` instances to make the changes to the html. Using purely DOMDocument there is a mess of recursion and rebuilding that you need to do which is hard to keep track of and feels awfully error prone.  My solution follows:

```php
<?php

$templates = TemplateRepository::fetchAll();

$classes = [
    'element_wrapper',
    'element',
    'name',
    'element_header',
];


foreach ($templates as $template) {
    // We need to guarantee a root element for DOMDocument to be happy. (strip later)
    $html = '<div>' . $template['html_body'] . '</div>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $finder = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $class_found = false; // track if we found a class / will have changes.
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        $div_nodes = $finder->query("//div[contains(@class,'$class')]");
        /** @var DOMNode $div_node */
        foreach ($div_nodes as $div_node) {
            $class_found = true;

            $content = $dom->saveHTML($div_node);

            // I know that the class I want to turn into a custom tag will come after the div opener, so replace that with the class.
            $content = preg_replace('@^<div class="' . $class . '([^>]+)>@', '<' . $class . ' class="\1>', $content);

            // Clean up empty class attribute...just cuz.
            $content = preg_replace("@<$class class=\"\s*\"@", "<$class", $content);

            // Replace closing div with closing custom tag.  We can assume the end </div> is our target because DOMDocument did the heavy lifting.
            $content = preg_replace('@</div>$@', "</$class>", $content);

            // Create a new dom document from our new html string.  We need this to create a DOMNode that we can import into our original.
            $dom_element = new DOMDocument();
            $dom_element->loadHTML($content);

            // We only want the original html, so just grab the first child of the body.
            $node = $dom_element->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->firstChild;

            // Import the new node into our original document so we can use it to replace our <div> version.
            $node = $dom->importNode($node, true);

            // Replace our original.
            $div_node->parentNode->replaceChild($node, $div_node);
        }
    }

    // Get the final updated html.
    $new_body = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->firstChild);

    // And finish by stripping off our wrapper div we added at the start.
    $new_body = preg_replace('@^<div>(.*)</div>@', '\1', $new_body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in php you may find useful [php-xml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) module.

I can't imagine why you want using custom tags, but you can work with div-s as  plain text. To close tags correctly use data-structure STACK (there is a [module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-stack.php) to work with data-structures, but you may need own 'smaller' one).

> < div> - adds element to stack
>
> < /div> -  deletes one.

Finally this way parse whole input text.

Comment: I'm working with templates inside of a WYSIWYG.  WYSIWYGs like <p> tags, and <p> tags have rules like "no divs or other p tags allowed." So I'm having to get creative.

Comment: I'll look into this as my next approach.  I'm experimenting with preg_replace and ->saveHTML() right now...but that may fall short soon.